# A tip for PHP & ASP on IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis, asp-classic, windows-server-2016

I'm developing a website with Classic ASP (yeah, I know it's 2017!) and I have a pretty heavy script that has many db writes and reads while it runs.

(Basically, it's a web based soccer game, and that heavy script is the match engine that simulates the match events while the game actually occurs minute-by-minute, while 1 minute ingame = every 20 seconds in reality).

I'm working with Windows 2016 Server on a VPS Server with 8GB RAM, using MySQL.

I already have a version of this running, an old one, and now I'm developing a better one, much more functional.

I thought about developing that engine with PHP, mainly because it's gonna be easier for my purpose since it partially supports OOP, and that's a huge advantage here, as it makes it much easier to store and access data.

How would you recommend to do that?

From your experience, what's the best way to run PHP on IIS? (I know there are some kind of plugins that do that)

And, what else should I take in account?

**Thank you for your time!**

Comment: This is off topic for SO. You might want to differ to https://php.iis.net/.

Comment: Php runs just fine in IIS as long as the extension is property installed. The idea of having an IIS instead of apache is to keep using parts of the old interface in asp? Maybe you should think about using Microsoft azure as it would seamlessly have both asp and php working as well as migrating everything to the cloud would let you escalate  easily

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge Can you recommend on a stable extension with good performance? Thank you buddy.

Comment: Depends on the IIS version but I think you could take a look at this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994592(v=ws.11).aspx)

In my opinion you should definitely give Azure a look... Once you go cloud you never come back! :)

Comment: Latest IIS version.
I'll give it a look. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run PHP on IIS.

http://php.iis.net/

As per my understanding you can also try  Zend Server community edition.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/

It's free, it's reliable,  good performance, and it has a web-based admin console.